# How to return field of record after update query with upsert as true in mongodb using pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to to insert record in mongodb but I dont want duplication so I am using `update` command with `upsert=true`

```
import pymongo
client = pymongo.MongoClient(settings.MONGO_DB_URI)
db = self.client[settings.MONGO_DB_NAME]
filter = {
    'my_id': '1234',
    'name': 'alok'
}
record = {
    'my_id': '1234',
    'name': 'alok',
    'marks': 26
}
status = db['mycollection'].update(filter, {'$setOnInsert': record}, upsert=True)  
print('id is ', status['my_id']) # this will not work but I want such behaviour
```

This code will insert record only if there is no existing record with matching filter values. So there are two case:
It will insert record
It will not insert record if already exist
In both the case I want to get `my_id`. How can I get my_id when update command execute?

Answer (score 0):

You can search for the document and then print out its ID

```
print('id is ', db['mycollection'].find_one(filter)['my_id'])
```

Comment: If I wont get any solution then I would do it like this. I am expecting getting `my_id` in one step on update command.